# Recommendation for a bluetooth mouse that works without a transceiver with 14.04

Tags: 14.04, mouse, bluetooth

I have a Dell E5570 that has only 3 usb ports, and can't afford to devote one to a mouse usb transceiver.     Can anybody recommend a mouse on the market that will connect directly with Ubuntu 14.04's bluetooth without requiring a transceiver.      I've read about [the blueman bluetooth manager](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/precise/blueman/) but I can't tell from the documentation whether it will work with 14.04 and if so with which mice.

Thanks very much for any suggestion.

Comment: Does your computer have an internal bluetooth module?  If not, you will have to use a USB adapter.

Comment: It will be better if you specify which bluetooth adapter /module is installed in your notebook.

Comment: Sorry that was dumb.   Here's what it says in the specs, don't know if this is enough to help:  555-BCMT : Intel Dual Band Wireless 8260 (802.11ac) W/ Bluetooth, whose details are described in http://ark.intel.com/products/86068/Intel-Dual-Band-Wireless-AC-8260

Comment: I am voting to close this question as hardware recommendations are off topic.

Answer (score 0):

If the machine does not have Bluetooth built into it, it will probably need the transceiver.

Another option is to purchase a USB hub, which will give you more ports.

Best bet is, check with Dell as to what mouse they recommend will work with the machine, it really is not an Ubuntu issue per se, at least not yet.

Chris